# How do I return a WebForm UserControl via ASP.NET MVC controller action method?

Tags: user-controls, webforms, asp.net-mvc-3

My app uses both Asp.net MVC and WebForms, is there a way to return a WebForm UserControl content via an MVC controller action method?

Answer (score 1):

```
return Redirect("MyWebFormRoute/MyWebForm.aspx");
```